# Losing all races by the same margin of time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, kinematics

Suppose two cars are racing along a (straight) road at a constant speed $v_{0}$ m/s. At time $t = 0$, Car 2 is ahead of Car 1 by $d_{0}$ meters; or, one could say, Car 1 is losing by $d_{0} / v_{0}$ seconds.

At time $t = 0$, Car 2 speeds up, with a constant acceleration of $a$ m/sec<sup>2</sup> for $t_{0}$ seconds, and then proceeds at the new speed $v_{0} + at_{0}$.

My question is this: At time 0, Car 1 is losing the race by $d_{0} / v_{0}$ seconds. How does Car 1's speed need to change in order to maintain this "margin of loss", regardless of the length of the race? That is, how does Car 1's speed need to change so that no matter how long the race, it will always lose by $d_{0} / v_{0}$ seconds?

Is there a closed form for this?

---

***Edit:*** Here's a way to understand the problem, completely separated from the physical interpretation.

Consider a function $c_{2}(t)$ defined as follows:

- $c_{2}(t) = vt + d$ (for some positive $v$ and $d$) for $t \lt 0$
- $c_{2}(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2 + vt + d$ for $0 \leq t \lt s$ (for some positive $s$, $a$)
- $c_{2}(t) = (as + v)t + (\frac{1}{2}as^2 + vs + d)$ for $s \leq t$

Now define a second function $c_{1}(t)$ such that for all $t$,

$\frac{c_{2}(t) - c_{1}(t)}{c_{1}'(t)} = d / v$

Is there a closed-form description of $c_1$?

Comment: I don't want the distance separating them to be $d_{0}$ I want the _time_ separating them to be constant: $d_{0} / v_{0}$. That is,  if at any time Car 2 is $d_{1}$ meters ahead of Car 1, I want Car 1 to be traveling at a speed $v_{1}$, where $d_{1} / v_{1} = d_{0} / v_{0}$.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. There is some proportion I'd imagine. I'll see what I can find.

Comment: It sounds like you want the following: Given the trajectory of Car 1, describe a trajectory where Car 2 always loses by $T$ seconds no matter the length of the race.

Comment: ok - so if car 2 has the new velocity $v_1$ then car 1 should accelerate to same velocity after extending distance to car 2 to $d_1:=d_0 \frac{v_1}{v_0}$ (since then $\frac{d_0}{v_0}=\frac{d_1}{v_1}$).

Comment: @Semiclassical yes, I think that describes it accurately.

Comment: I changed the title; do revert it if you don't care for it.

Answer (score 0):

Car 1 just has to make sure that its speed at any point is the same as Car 2's speed at the same point. If you like, Car 1 executes a video replay of Car 2, delayed by $d_0/v_0$ seconds.

Comment: But if Car 1 is delaying by $d_{0} / v_{0}$ seconds, doesn't it allow Car 2 to get ahead, and thus have a greater "margin of loss"? I'll try to work out what the equation is and see if that works.

Comment: You don't have to work out any equations. You just have to visualise the first car as a video replay of the second car. Wherever Car 2 is, Car 1 gets there exactly $d_0/v_0$ seconds later.

Comment: Suppose at time 0, car 2 is at position 100 (100 m ahead of car 1, if car 1's position at time 0 is 0); each car traveling 20 m/s. At time 0, car 2 accelerates by 1 m/s^2 for 10 seconds. At time $t = 1$ then, car 2 is at position 120.5; but where is car 1? I have to know where it is before I know how fast it needs to go. That's my question.

Comment: @MattGutting: I really can't make it any simpler.

Comment: I get what you're saying; I just don't see that it _must_ be correct.

Comment: Well, think about it until you do.